# When I remove an item, and then I add a new one, the information of removed item remains

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use the recycler view for add and remove the blocks with the edittext, 
but when I remove a block, and then add a new one, the information from the removed one returns to a new one, but I need a clean block to be added

```
 delete.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            try {
                connector.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, connector.size());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

 add.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            try {
                connector.add(position + 1, "");
                notifyItemInserted(position + 1);
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

ViewHolder full:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView delete;
    TextInputEditText typeOfConnector;

    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_garbage);
        typeOfConnector = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type_of_connector_et);

        delete.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            try {
                connector.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, connector.size());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        add.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            try {
                connector.add(position + 1, "");
                notifyItemInserted(position + 1);
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code where you populating your `ViewHolder` with data

Comment: you can see it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need all three commands:

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, connector.size());
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

For your use-case: just `notifyItemRemoved(position);` will do

Now in your bindViewHolder method, you need to set the Edittext to the respective string in connector.

Comment: In bindViewHolder i set the text for et ("") and it work, thanks. 
if there is no answer better, I confirm your